# jquery ui slider animation on dragging the handle

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

I have a question about the jquery ui slider, have been searching for a while now but can not find a working anwser.

For a project I am using the http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#steps jQuery ui Slider.
It works well and gets most of the stuff done.

I use steps of 250 and when a user clicks on e.g 250 or 500 the slider handle animates/slides to the value.

But when a user is holding(dragging) the handle and drags it manually it does not animate/slide the steps but just goes to the next value very ugly.

Does anyone know how to make the handle animated/sliding when a user is holding it manually instead of clicking on some predefined values?

Thanks!

Comment: But if you're dragging the slider to move it, and then you animate it, the slider will jump out from under your mouse which results in weird behavior to the user.

Comment: But it is being dragged in steps of 250, so that happens anyways however without clean animation. It's just very jumpy now.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery UI Slider(version 1.9.2) doesn’t support dragging animation. You have to change the library code I think.

Here is the patch javascript code

```
    (function( $, undefined ) {

        $.extend($.ui.slider.prototype.options, {
            dragAnimate: true
        });

        var _mouseCapture = $.ui.slider.prototype._mouseCapture;
        $.widget("ui.slider", $.extend({}, $.ui.slider.prototype, {
            _mouseCapture: function(event) {
                _mouseCapture.apply(this, arguments);
                this.options.dragAnimate ? this._animateOff = false : this._animateOff = true;
                return true;
            }
        }));

    }(jQuery));
```